# The specified module could not be found error on app configuration

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am using `geodjango` to implement Google Map API in my web application. I configured the database in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'geodjango_project',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432'
    },
}
```

I got this error:

```
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

then according to the instruction of the error, I added `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal202'` and this error was thrown:

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup       
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, 
in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 
39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\geodjango-project-Aa0-CBie\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Have you installed GDAL library?

Comment: I installed OSGeo4W and after your comment I also installed GDAL library still getting same error